# jQuery change event doesn't fire on specified selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("select.form-control").change(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

In my DOM there is a variable number of `select` tags that I need to work on, but I can't seem to access their values (in this case, their values) using the above function. Any idea why this is not working?

Edit:

The piece of code that should trigger the event:

```
     <div class="box box-solid ship-grid">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Victory II-Class Star Destroyer</h3>
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="ship-id-0" id="ship-id-0">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3 class="box-title points-counter GreenBold"><span class="point-counter" id="point-counter-0">85</span> points 
                    <i class="fa fa-times delete-from-grid" title="Delete this ship" onclick="deleteShipGrid(this)"></i></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <img src="images/ships/empire/victory-II.png" class="ship-grid-image amd-center-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                        <span class="control-label" style="margin-top: 10px"><img src="images/icons/officer.png" class="grid-upgrade-icon"> Select an Officer</span>
                        <select name="officer-0" id="officer-0" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <option value="0">No officer</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-12" value="12">[ +3 ] Director Isard •</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-13" value="13">[ +3 ] Defense Liason </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-14" value="14">[ +3 ] Weapons Liason </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-15" value="15">[ +3 ] Veteran Captain </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-11" value="11">[ +7 ] Wulff Yularen •</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-10" value="10">[ +10 ] Admiral Chiraneau •</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                        <span class="control-label" style="margin-top: 10px"><img src="images/icons/weapons.png" class="grid-upgrade-icon"> Select a Weapons Team</span>
                        <select name="weapons-team-0" id="weapons-team-0" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <option value="0">No weapons team</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-17" value="17">[ +5 ] Sensor Team </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-18" value="18">[ +6 ] Flight Controllers </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-16" value="16">[ +7 ] Gunnery Team </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                        <span class="control-label" style="margin-top: 10px"><img src="images/icons/off.png" class="grid-upgrade-icon"> Select an Offensive Retrofit</span>
                        <select name="offensive-retro-0" id="offensive-retro-0" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <option value="0">No offensive retrofit</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-46" value="46">[ +5 ] Expanded Hangar Bay </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-47" value="47">[ +5 ] Point-Defense Reroute </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                        <span class="control-label" style="margin-top: 10px"><img src="images/icons/turbo.png" class="grid-upgrade-icon"> Select Turbolasers</span>
                        <select name="turbolasers-0" id="turbolasers-0" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <option value="0">No turbolasers</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-36" value="36">[ +5 ] XX-9 Turbolasers </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-38" value="38">[ +6 ] X-17 Turbolasers </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-35" value="35">[ +8 ] H9 Turbolasers </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-37" value="37">[ +10 ] Enhanced Armament </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                        <span class="control-label" style="margin-top: 10px"><img src="images/icons/ion.png" class="grid-upgrade-icon"> Select Ion Cannons</span>
                        <select name="ions-0" id="ions-0" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <option value="0">No ion cannons</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-39" value="39">[ +4 ] Leading Shots </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-40" value="40">[ +5 ] Ion Cannon Batteries </option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-41" value="41">[ +8 ] Overload Pulse </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs12">
                        <span class="control-label" style="margin-top: 10px"><img src="images/icons/title.png" class="grid-upgrade-icon"> Select a vessel title</span>
                        <select name="tilte-0" id="title-0" class="form-control" style="margin-top: 10px">
                            <option value="0">No title</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-32" value="32">[ +8 ] Warlord •</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-33" value="33">[ +5 ] Corrupter •</option><option class="tooltip-upgrade-34" value="34">[ +12 ] Dominator •</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="flagship-0" id="flagship-0"> Use this ship as flagship
                      </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
```

Imagine I have more than one of these boxes, and I need a unique function to get every select value plus thier name attribute.

A big part of the Javascript code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").css("height", $("#selector").css("height"));

    <?php if($faction_char == 'e'){ ?>
    $("#li-fge").addClass("active");
    <? }else{ ?>
    $("#li-fgr").addClass("active");
    <? } ?>

    var ship_counter = 0;
    var squadron_counter = 0;

    // List object to be populated on submit
    var list = new Object();

    var ship_array = new Array();
    var squadron_array = new Array();

    $('.boostrap-slider').slider();

    $('#points-slider').slider().on('slide', function (ev) {
        setTotalPoints();
    });

    $('#total-points').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
        checkPoints();
    });

    $('#current-points').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
        checkPoints();
    });

    $(".ship-selector").click(function () {
        var ship_id = $(this).attr("ship-id");
        var vessel = $(this).attr("vessel");

        // Ship object initialization
        var ship_object = new Object();
        ship_object.builder_id = 0;
        ship_object.list_id = 0;
        ship_object.ship_id = 0;
        ship_object.officer_id = 0;
        ship_object.weapons_team_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.support_team_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.offensive_retrofit_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.defensive_retrofit_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.ordnance_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.turbolasers_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.ion_cannons_1_id = 0;
        ship_object.weapons_team_2_id = 0;
        ship_object.support_team_2_id = 0;
        ship_object.offensive_retrofit_2_id = 0;
        ship_object.defensive_retrofit_2_id = 0;
        ship_object.ordnance_2_id = 0;
        ship_object.turbolasers_2_id = 0;
        ship_object.ion_cannons_2_id = 0;

        $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "server/get_ship.php",
                    data: {
                        'id': ship_id,
                        'vessel': vessel,
                        'counter': ship_counter
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#ship-grid").append(data);
                        ship_object.builder_id = ship_counter;
                        ship_object.ship_id = parseInt($("#ship-id-" + ship_counter.toString()).val());
                        ship_array.push(ship_object);
                        ship_counter++;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("AJAX error.");
                    }
                });
    });

    $("select.form-control").change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

    $("#objective_1").change(function () {
        $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "server/get_objective.php",
                    data: {
                        'id': $("#objective_1").val()
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var domData = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $("#obj-1-img").attr("src","images/objectives/" + domData["rows"][0]["cell"][7]);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("AJAX error.");
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: Should work. Please show the rest of your code & sample HTML. Might be script placement. Might be a lack of DOM ready. Hard to tell from that snippet.

Comment: Do you mean values for all select or just changed one??

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to access their values (in this case, their values)"?

Comment: it should work.. or you may use `onchange` function

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear. It's not that I can't get the select, it's that the change event doesn't happen in first place. No alert in fact is actually shown. I'm updating the question with more code.

Comment: How is that jQuery included in the page?

Comment: @Popnoodles The function is inside a `$(document).ready(function () { });` with many other jQuery function that work. The page is a detailed generator that gets the code from many AJAX calls.

Comment: that's an important detail, and it's the reason why your code isn't working.  you need to use $('select.function-control').on('change', function() ....

Comment: The only different thing from the other `.change` functions I'm using is that the elements I want to target come from an AJAX call, and the code is included into the page using an `.append`

Comment: If they are dynamic, you need to use a delegated event handler. See update below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention ajax loading. Use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor element (e.g. `document`):

e.g. add this

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change',"select.form-control", function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3p1rtjb0/1/

Delegated events work by listening for the event to bubble up to the ancestor. It then applies the selector to only the elements in the bubble-chain (so is very efficient). It then calls the function on any matching elements that caused the event.

The upshot is that the elements only need to match at event time (not when the event was registered).

**Note:** I last yeat found a bug, related to styling, that means delegated mouse events attached to `body` do not fire (if the calculated body height is 0). For that reason I recommend you always use `document` as the default for delegated event handler (if nothing else is closer/convenient).

Comment: seems to be required fix

Comment: The change function is already in a $(document).ready function. Actually, there are other change functions in the same ready function that work. Could it be that these select are generated via AJAX and they don't trigger because of it?

Comment: yes.  you need to use "on" if the element is added after DOM ready.

Comment: Changed the code from `.change(function () {` to `.on('change', function () {`.. sadly nothing new. You can see the work at its own [link](http://armada.hivelabs.solutions/fleet_builder_test.php?f=2). Just select a ship from the grey box near the bottom of the page and any select that appears should trigger an alert.

Comment: @nevetz1911: The example you just posted is missing the selector, so will not actually be delegated. please use `$(document).on('change',"select.form-control", function ()` as shown.